# Can I use Orbited as a HTTP server for dynamic content?

Tags: ajax, dynamic, comet, orbited

Comet Server Orbited can serve static files from paths specified in it's config file under *[static]* section. I wonder if it's possible to serve dynamic content via orbited?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no.

This is why orbited is usually paired with a web framework (django, rails, etc.) and a standard webserver.